# Warnings after octave installation

Tags: octave

I am getting following warning after launching octave.
i used installation instruction from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave_Windows%20-%20MinGW/Octave%203.6.0%20for%20Windows%20MinGW%20installer/).

What could be the issue? Are these major warnings?
I am using windows.

```
warning: gmsh does not seem to be present some functionalities will be disabled
warning: dx does not seem to be present some functionalities will be disabled
warning: function C:\Octave\Octave3.6.0_gcc4.6.2\share\octave\packages\statistics- 
1.1.0\fstat.m shadows a core library function
```

Comment: See also [this section of the Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows#Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you have installed packages that you probably do not need (otherwise you would already noticed more than just the warning message)

```
warning: gmsh does not seem to be present some functionalities will be disabled
```

You have the msh package installed and loaded. This package uses gmsh hence the warning. If you don't use this package remove it `pkg uninstall msh` or turn off its automatic loading at startup with `pkg rebuild -noauto msh`

```
warning: dx does not seem to be present some functionalities will be disabled
```

I don't know exactly which package uses dx but I'm guessing the problem is same as the msh. Run `pkg unload all` and then try to load them one by one until you find the warning. Fix as in the case of msh package.

```
warning: function C:\Octave\Octave3.6.0_gcc4.6.2\share\octave\packages\statistics- 
1.1.0\fstat.m shadows a core library function
```

The `fstat()` function from the statistics package is shadowing the same function with same name from Octave core. The one in core is already deprecated so don't worry about this warning. It will go away after Octave 3.8 is released.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the

> warning: dx does not seem to be present some functionalities will be disabled

in Ubuntu, you have to edit the following file

> sudo nano /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/startup/octaverc

and you should comment this line  `pkg ("load", "auto");`

This is the solution for this warning .